# Permutation of different types of objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have to arrange $8$ books, including $2$ of English, such that the books of English are never together on a shelf.

I tried to do it by first finding the total number of arrangements, which is $8!$, and subtract from it the number of arrangements if English books were kept together, which is $2!×6!×2!$.

There are $2$ English books, and they can arrange among themselves in $2!$ ways. For each of the $2!$ ways, there are $6!$ ways for the rest of $6$ books to arrange themselves and lastly, we can either keep English books first or vice versa.

The answer I got is $37440$, but the correct answer is $30240$.

I need some clarification on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: There are more than two ways to place the English books.  Since there are a total of eight books, you can place the first English book in seven ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can view "Two English books together" as a single object/book. Then there are $7$ objects left to *arrange*, which is simply $7!$. English books themselves can swap, which is $2!$. In conclusion, by subtracting the unwanted ways, you have  $8!-2!7!=30240$.

Answer (score 0):

Your error was in your assumption that "we can either keep English books first or vice versa."  Since there are a total of eight books, the pair of English books must begin in one of the first seven positions.  With that correction to your solution, we obtain $8! - 7 \cdot 6!2! = 30,240$.

Answer (score 0):

Your method only subtracts the ways where both English books are together at the start or end of a row. However there could be any number from $0$ to $6$ books before the two English books, so you need to subtract $7\times 2!\times 6!$ instead.